# Popup a dialog use jquery mobile in phone gap

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, cordova, popup

I'm developing a phonegap project, I wanna popup a dialog of error information. I learn some from the demos of jQuery mobile, here is the link http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup/#&ui-state=dialog I used the code of it and in my js file I use popup('open') to open it.

Here is part of my html code

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="dialogZ" data-overlay-theme="b"  data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" data-transition="pop">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1 align="center">Sign in failed</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p id="SigninError"></p>
    <span align="center"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-rel="back">OK</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is part of my js code

```
else if (data == "Error2") {

    var message = '<p align="center">Wrong username or password</p>';
    SigninError.empty().append(message);
    $('#dialogZ').popup('open');
    }
```

I wanna have the effect like the demo but it didn't work.

Anyone knows why? It seems I can not have the css work properly, but I have included the jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css. Need helps!!

Comment: your html and js for the pop-up works fine [DEMO]:http://jsfiddle.net/mXjHJ/543/ there may be error in the login so plese share some ore code.

Comment: I have solve the problem it was the css problem. In the demo, the code that the official website provides is not enough. I add some code to my html file.

Comment: <div data-role="popup" id="dialogZ" data-overlay-theme="b"  data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" data-transition="fade" class="ui-popup">
     <div data-role="header" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-a">
  <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading">Sign in failed</h1>
     </div>
     <div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p id="SigninError"></p>
  <span align="center"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-rel="back">OK</a></span>
     </div>
 </div>

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add code in the comment. In this way I can get the effect that I need. I revised some colour attributes in the query.mobile.1.4.0.css, maybe that caused some problems so I could not get the effect

Answer (score 0):

ya i got same issue before 4 months finally i got a solution. when you append content inside the popupview at the time u must call like this.....

**JS**

```
$('#dialogZ').popup();
$('#dialogZ').popup('open');
```

**or**

```
$('#dialogZ').popup();
setTimeout(function(){
$('#dialogZ').popup('open');
},100);
```

**HTML**

your data-role popup must inside the content of your calling page

Answer (score -1):

Ideally data-transition should be on the link which triggers popup. since you are opening the popup in code, there is an additional attribute for $(dialog).open function, u need to pass the transition as part of open function., [jquery doc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/popup/methods.html)

Comment: Verify before answering.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your answer, I have tried that method before :-)